# PUG multiple Iteration in Express Framework with JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, pug

I am developing small app with Express and PUG and I want to make like this:

[image]

index.pug

```
ul#restaurants-list
        li
          img.restaurant-img(alt='Mission Chinese Food', src='/images/reactchat.png')
          h1
            =`${name}`
          p
            ='URL : ' + `${url}`
          p
            =`${explanation}`
          a(href=`/${name}`) View Details
```

index.js

```
    let express = require('express');
let router = express.Router();
let bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const fs = require('fs');
router.use(bodyParser.json()); // to support JSON-encoded bodies
router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ // to support URL-encoded bodies
  extended: true
}));
// LowDB Module
const low = require('lowdb');
const FileSync = require('lowdb/adapters/FileSync');
const shortid = require('shortid');
// Save DB in db.json
const adapter = new FileSync('./public/db.json');
const db = low(adapter)

db.defaults({
  project: [],
  cert: [],
  education: []
})


/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  let data = db.get('project').find().value();
  let sid = shortid.generate();
  console.log(data);
  res.render('index', {
    dataarray: data,
    id: sid,
    name: data.name,
    url: data.url,
    explanation: data.explanation,
    imgurl: data.imgurl
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

and I can make it one li element and it works but I have no idea how can I iterate the li element like the image. data are from JSON file and I get it with lowDB dependency.

db.json file looks like this

```
{
  "project": [{
      "name": "React Chat App",
      "url": "https://sangumee.herokuapp.com/",
      "explanation": "THis Project is good",
      "imgurl": "images/reactchat.png",
      "date": ""
    },
    {
      "name": "React Chat App",
      "url": "https://sangumee.herokuapp.com/",
      "explanation": "THis Project is good",
      "imgurl": "images/reactchat.png",
      "date": ""
    }
  ],
  "cert": [],
  "education": []
}
```

So the problem is How can I save multiple json data in index.js to get it to PUG file. And How can receive the multiple data from index.js and spread it in li element iteration.

I already check pug doc and several question that related with this problem but still I don't have idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `each` operator like this: ([docs](https://pugjs.org/language/iteration.html))

```
- var restaurants = dataarray.project
ul#restaurants-list
  each restaurant in restaurants
    li
      img.restaurant-img(alt='Mission Chinese Food', src='/images/reactchat.png')
      h1= restaurant.name
      p= 'URL : ' + restaurant.url
      p= restaurant.explanation
      a(href= '/' + restaurant.name) View Details
```

That first line with the variable declaration points the iterator to where I believe the restaurants live in your route.  You could also do it like this with no extra variables:

```
each restaurant in dataarray.project
```